# Jamaican/Caribbean insect, plant identification keys/field guides

Tags: species-identification, botany, entomology, book-recommendation, trees

Where can I find **plant and insect identification keys and Field guides for Jamaica** specifically, or for the Caribbean as a whole?

I've searched Amazon and google for Jamaican and Caribbean identification keys/field guides, to no avail. I'm taking pictures of organisms in my backyard, and I want to identify them and post them to iNaturalist. For my own sake I want to be able to identify them myself, prior to and independent of the (long) wait for a community ID to be given and confirmed.

Answer (score 4):

I've never been to nor botanized Jamaica or the Caribbean, but a quick Google search turned up the following references for Jamaican plants:

- Iremonger, S., 2002. Guide to the Plants in the Blue Mountains of Jamaica. University of West Indies Press, 280p. ISBN: 9789766400316
- Fawcett, W. and A. B. Rendle. 1910. Flora of Jamaica, containing Descriptions of the Flowering Plants known from the island. Longmans & Company. [Found here](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/23232#page/6/mode/1up).

[image]

You can also find a list of Jamaican species on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Flora_of_Jamaica) and a list of medicinal plants in Jamaica [here](https://www.herbalstudies.net/_media/resources/library/Medicinal-Plants-of-Jamaica.pdf).

Comment: I've never seen "botany" in verb form as botanize/botanized; I like it.

Comment: @Bryan apparently you didn't like it enough to upvote :p. But yeah, "botanize" is quite commonly used among plant folks. I never really thought it strange, but I guess if you consider ornithize (we usually say "birding") or herpatize ("herp hunting"?) which aren't commonly used, it does seem kind of odd 0.o